# Idris: Implicit parameters in records

Tags: idris

When I try to compile this example

```
record R where
    f: () -> {t: Type} -> t
```

I get this error:

```
Type mismatch between
        () -> t1 (Type of f)
and
        () -> t (Expected type)

Specifically:
        Type mismatch between
                t1
        and
                t
```

On the other hand this example

```
record R where
    f: {t: Type} -> () -> t
```

works just fine. Can you tell me what's wrong with the first one?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I suppose implicit parameters must appear before non-implicit ones

Comment: Yeah, maybe. It's a bit weird, because this is no problem with an equivalent definition using data:

`data D: Type where MkD: (f: () -> {t: Type} -> t) -> D`

Comment: I also had problems instantiating such a record. I didn't have the problem with data. Unfortunately, I have no simple example for this.

Comment: You cannot instantiate such a record because it is not possible. This part `{t: Type} -> t` of the function type says that given *any* type, you can build a term of that type. But this is not possible e.g. for the empty type (`Void`).

Comment: Yes that's true for this example. That statement was related to another more complex example, where this is no problem. But in the meantime, I have come to the conclusion that it was my fault and was just related to inference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Idris: sometimes the `->` operator is not right-associative: [issue #4077](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/issues/4077).

To see it we can desugar the record syntax:

```
data R : Type where
  MkR : (() -> {t : Type} -> t) -> R
```

Now we need to manually implement the `f` projection. It turns out that

```
f : R -> (() -> {t : Type} -> t)
f (MkR g) = g
```

does *not* typecheck, but

```
f : R -> () -> {t : Type} -> t
f (MkR g) = g
```

does.

It seems to me Idris uses the first variant to desugar `record` into `data`, hence the error you observed.